# How to use GPIO Port Control (GPIOPCTL) in ARM Cortex M4 TM4C123G microcontroller?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, gpio

I am trying to interface an ultrasonic sensor with ARM Cortex M4 mcu. Since I am  using and edge-triggered timer that calculates the time between the rising and falling edge of the echo of the sensor, What is the alternate function that I should be assigning to the echo input pin ?
I have found the following configuration on http://cortex-m.com/tm4c-lessons/:

```
void Timer0_init(void)
{
SYSCTL->RCGCTIMER |=(1U<<0); 
SYSCTL->RCGCGPIO |=(1U<<1); 
GPIOB->DIR &=~ECHO;
GPIOB->DEN |=ECHO;
GPIOB->AFSEL |=ECHO;
GPIOB->PCTL &=~0x0F000000;
GPIOB->PCTL |= 0x07000000;
TIMER0->CTL &=~1;
TIMER0->CFG =4;
TIMER0->TAMR = 0x17;
TIMER0->CTL |=0x0C;
TIMER0->CTL |=1;
}
```

I used the data sheet to understand every line but for the lines I don't understand :

```
GPIOB->PCTL &=~0x0F000000;
GPIOB->PCTL |= 0x07000000;
```

I guess the first line is just a reset, and the second line selects the peripheral function, but I can't understand or find what does setting the pin he used for input with 7 in the PCTL register?

Comment: These registers are not inherent for the ARM core, but specific to the micro-controller you are using.

Comment: I added the type of the microcontroller , thank you. @EugeneSh.

Comment: @PeterJ I really don't understand your comment ! :D

Comment: you are having a C language problem with those two lines of code or having a what does this do to the peripheral problem with these two lines of code?  one you look at C documentation/tutorials for the other you look at the chip manual for.

Comment: shold be: `GPIOB->PCTL &=~0x0F000000;
GPIOB->PCTL |= 0x07000000;`  It is not understandable for humans. Folks from ARM & TI have written massive .h files with human readable definitions. Who can remember what is in the particular bit or bitsield

Comment: @old_timer I am having problem with what does this do to the pin. I looked the register in the data sheet but couldn't find what does setting the pin with 7 do ?

Comment: @PeterJ I am still in the learning process so I try to understand every line and how to extract it from the data sheet and this kinda of stuff before moving to abstraction.

Comment: it is right  there in the manual you are selecting the alternate function for that pin, so you look at the alternate function table for the pins, across the top it says the GPIOPCTL PMCx encoding for that function, then you take the function you want look at the encoding and write that to those bits in the GPIOPCTL register for that pin.

Comment: @old_timer I have found it and now I see what the 7 represents T0CCP0.. Thank you this was really helpful.

Comment: for the msp430 which is not arm and not what you have but is also a ti product, the alternate functions and other items I think they keep in the datasheet then how to talk to the registers in another manual, so you have to jump back and forth, for this part both items were in the same manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms376e/spms376e.pdf) on page 688f the used bits `27:24` of this register are used to set the alternate function to be used on pin 6. According to `GPIOB->PCTL` the configured pin is PB6.

Now you can see on page 1351 Table 23-5 which alternate function is set. In this case it is `T0CCP0` which is either a pwm, a capture or a compare funtcion based on the pin direction and peripheral configuration.

`GPIOB->PCTL &=~0x0F000000;` is used to reset the pin 6 function, without touching the other pins.

`GPIOB->PCTL |= 0x07000000;` sets the pin 6 function, without changing the others.